# Simulation waveform differs from testbench delay specification

Tags: verilog, testbench

I'm running the following Verilog code, and I got the image below as a result.

I'm curious why the *dout* and *start* signal transitions don't coincide with the delays definitions on the testbench.

Does anyone know the reason for that?

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps 
module tb_adc_sp_ctrl 
#( PERIOD=20 ) 
; 
reg start; 
reg sclk; 
reg rst; 
reg dout;
reg [2:0] addr;
wire [11:0] data;
wire din;
wire cs;
wire sclk_adc;
initial begin
    addr    = 3'b001;
    rst     = 1'b1;
    start   = 1'b0;
    dout    = 1'b0;
    sclk    = 1'b0;
    #60;
    rst     = 1'b0;
    #90
    start   = 1'b1;
    #130   
    start   = 1'b0;
    #285 
    dout    = 1'b1;
    #385 
    dout    = 1'b0;
end

always begin
    #(PERIOD/2)  
    sclk=0;
    #(PERIOD)
    sclk=1;  
end
endmodule
```

[image: Test bech results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation waveforms show the expected delays.

All of your delay specifications for these 2 signals are inside the `initial` block, and they add together.

The `initial` block begins execution at time=0ns.  At that time, you set `start`=0, which is what we see in waves.

`#60;` instructs the simulator to advance by 60ns.

`#90;` instructs the simulator to advance by 90ns: 60ns + 90ns = 150ns.  At that time, you set `start`=1, which is what we see in waves.

`#130;` instructs the simulator to advance by 130ns: 150ns + 130ns = 280ns.  At that time, you set `start`=0, which is what we see in waves.

You set `dout`=0 at time=0ns, then set it to 1 at time=60+90+130+285=565.